# Merging/updating child tables in sqlalchemy 2.0

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I am learning `sqlalchemy` and trying to understand how to update parents and children at the same time. Take the modified example from `sqlalchemy` docs:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent_table"

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = mapped_column(String, unique=True)
    children = relationship("Child", back_populates="parent")


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child_table"

    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = mapped_column(String, unique=True)
    parent_id = mapped_column(ForeignKey("parent_table.id"))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="children")
```

The modification is that each table has a unique constraint on one of the columns. Call this a 'proxy' primary key. I want to implement the following logic:

1. Create parent(s) and children model instances in Python
2. Update the database so that any parent that does not exist by unique name gets added, along with their associate children. IF the parent or any children already exist by name, skip these entries

I've done this type of flow in postgres before with a series of `insert into ... on conflict ... returning ...` for the parent, then writing an insert query for each child using the parent's returned id. It seems pretty accessible to duplicate this, nearly verbatim, using `sqlalchemy core`, but I'm trying to learn how to do it using the 'ORM way'.

Updating a single parent works as expected with some form of the following:

```
with session.begin():
    parent = Parent(**kwargs)
    c1 = Child(**kwargs)
    c2 = Child(**kwargs)
    parent.children = [c1, c2]
```

However, if that parent already exists by name, I get an expected error. I tried using `merge()` but found out through various posts and the docs that this only works with the primary key, which I don't have ahead of time because it is autoincremented. Because of this, I've also tried various forms of `try` `except` blocks to query a parent by name, get it's id, and add children to it - this generally makes sense, but I'm still unsure how to handle the case of skipping duplicate children without explicitly checking each one (which feels like what the 'magic' of using sqlalchemy in the first place is trying to avoid).

Answer (score 1):

The ORM is not meant to solve everything.  You have to pick the right layer to be effective.  It is just to save time (performance and dev time) when it can.  Many times you have to use core anyways for one or both those reasons.  The ORM is not meant to be a perfect abstraction layer as much as it is a time saver.  This is expected.

Ie.  Just like a regular `SQL` `UPDATE` is going to **crush** looping over different groups of objects and setting an attribute to a specific value and calling `session.flush()` and submitting a gazillion single `UPDATE` statements.

So `upsert` is still your best bet.  There is a specific ORM section that describes importing the correct `insert()` for your dialect to then perform this type of operation.

[orm-upsert-statements](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#orm-upsert-statements)

The great thing about SQLAlchemy 2+ is that the core and orm layers are now much easier to switch between.

## Other references

This is from 2019 but I think is still relevant:

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4448